# login page cant find shake for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication

I have a basic login page where users enter credentials. The box for login is supposed to shake with text coming up that it is an invalid login if the entered credentials are wrong.

Everything was working correctly then someone who is working on same site as me made a few small changes and pushed to github and this caused an error where `shake` could no longer be located.

I went through the log reverted all the changes (nothing major just changing a few echo commands) and the error still continues. I swapped where the `.shake` is called so the text about invalid login still comes up so the system is functioning but I would still like to figure out why shake is not working.

My jquery files are in same directory as `login.php`. I can post `loginuser.php` if it will help but all it does it echo "successful login" on valid login and does nothing on invalid login.

This is the error I get

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).shake is not a function

Edit: I tried using $('#loginfo').effect( "shake" ); with my scripts sources as
`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>` instead and got this error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).effect is not a function

The code I'm using:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.shake.js"></script>
    <script> //used online tutorial for how to do shake animation
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#login').click(function() {
             var username = $("#username").val();
             var password = $("#password").val();
             if (username == '' || password == '') {
               $("#login").val('Login')
               $("#invalid").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Must enter both username and password. ");
               $('#loginfo').shake();
             }
             var dataString = 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password;
             if ($.trim(username).length > 0 && $.trim(password).length > 0) {
               $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "loginuser.php",
                 data: dataString,
                 cache: false,
                 beforeSend: function() {
                   $("#login").val('Connecting...');
                 },
                 success: function(data) {
                   if (data) {
                     $("body").load("index.php").hide().fadeIn(1500).delay(6000);
                   } else {
                     $("#login").val('Login')
                     $("#invalid").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Invalid username and password. ");
                     $('#loginfo').shake();
                   }
                 }
               });

             }
             return false;
           });
         });
    </script>
    <section id="loginfo">
        <form method="post" action="">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Login</legend>
                <p>Username <input type="text" name="username" class="input" autocomplete="off" id="username"/></p>
                <p>Password <input type="password" name="password" class="input"     autocomplete="off" id="password"/></p>
                <input type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Log In" id="login"/> 
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </section>
    <section id="invalid">
    </section>
    <p>Not Registered? <a href="register.php"> Register Here.</a></p>
</div>
<?php get_template($template = "footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Is jquery.ui.shake.js read by your navigator (does it return 404 in the console) ?

Comment: how would I check this? When I go to network tab jquery.ui.shake.js shows status 200 although im not sure im looking in correct place.

Comment: yes, that's the correct place - I don't see where your error came from :/ Maybe you'll have better chance with this: https://api.jqueryui.com/shake-effect/

Comment: thanks ill check that out. I just have no clue why shake broke out of nowhere I even tried getting a fresh copy of my jquery files with no luck

Comment: I just tried using the shake-effect rather then .shake and I got this error login.php:56 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).effect is not a function

Comment: here a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4d75ksgk/ I think you need jquery-ui.js